# RabbitMQ dotNet Client's EventingBasicConsumer.Received cannot be fired more than once simultaneously?

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I use RabbitMQ.Client(I got it from NuGet) to access RabbitMQ. This is my message consumer's code:

```
        const string EXCHANGE_NAME = "EXCHANGE3";
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection()) {
            using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel()) {
                channel.ExchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, ExchangeType.Topic, false, true, null);
                string queueName = channel.QueueDeclare();
                channel.BasicQos(0, 4, false); //I want to handle 4 messages simultaneously
                EventingBasicConsumer consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (o, e) => {
                    string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Body);
                    Console.WriteLine("received: " + data);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("done."); //Received event will not be fired again before done.
                };

                string consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

                channel.QueueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, "myTopic");
                Console.WriteLine("Listening press ENTER to quit");
                Console.ReadLine();
                channel.QueueUnbind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, "myTopic", null);
            }
        }
```

It's almost copied from RabbitMQ's official tutorial. Notice that I use a Sleep method to simulate a long time task, and I find that the Received event cannot be fired simultaneously. In other words, I can only handle the messages one by one, that's not what I want. How can I make it right?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Our solution is basically:

```
consumer.Received += (o,e) => {
    // setup...
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // real work done here
    });
};
```

That is, the consumer launches new threads/tasks (up to some limit). I've omitted the task count limiting logic etc. for simplicity.